# When you Checkpoint a VM, at what point is the state saved?

Tags: hyper-v, checkpoint

In Hyper-V, if you create a Standard Checkpoint on a VM, is the disk and memory state frozen when you start creating the checkpoint, or when the checkpoint has finished saving, or at some other point in between the two?

Answer (score 0):

I did some informal testing in Hyper-V in Windows 11 with an 8GB VM.

My findings are that roughly a second after clicking Checkpoint, the VM freezes for a little less than a second, and that's the point where the state is saved.  (The checkpoint continues to save in the background after this.)

Reverting takes me back to the point where the VM froze.